# Find the equation of the tangent line to the curve at the given point. (Let y be a function of x.)

Tags: calculus

f(x) = x cot(x) at the point with x-coordinate  π/ 4.
I need help. I don't know how to solve for this problem

Comment: The first thing you should do is differentiate $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The slope of your tangent line is given by $f'(\frac{\pi}{4})$ and you know it goes through the point $(\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4}\cot(\pi/4))$.